# How do I change the path that Visual Studio is using to find metadata files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I moved my VS project on my local machine. Now when I try to build it breaks because it is looking for metadata file in the old location. How can I change these paths?

```
Error   1   Metadata file 'C:\somelocation\somelocation\kb.dll' could not be found
```

Where can I tell visual studio where to look for these files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move your project around as much as anything. Normally, the metadata files are compiled within the DLL or EXE files that you create (VB, C#). If you receive this error, it normally means that something must be cleaned and fully rebuild.

I once had the same error but from a system (BCL!) file after I rearranged some things on my system. It helped to really clean everything, including `TEMP`, `obj` etc and restart.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clean'? I have run the clean solution. There must be a way to tell VS not to look at that path right??

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find that file in your project file ".csproj". You can edit it in Notepad or any other editor.